# revealing text within a webpage on link

Tags: html, text, onclick

is there a simple way to reveal text within a webpage using a link without altering the web address or using an iframe? maybe with an 'onclick' function? im pretty new to new code so not sure where to start.. ive attached a picture of what exaclty im after, fairly simple. im already using an iframe as the main interface so another one would get messy in terms of a default menu. there must be a simple fix.. any help would be really appreciated. 
thanks, Aaron

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the text you want to hide until click inside hidden container, like this:

```
<div id="HiddenTextContainer" style="display: none;">
   Hello, I will become visible when you click something else
</div>
```

Next step is add that JavaScript code to the page, for example inside the `<head>` section:

```
function ShowHiddenText() {
    document.getElementById("HiddenTextContainer").style.display = "block";
}
```

And finally have such code:

```
<span onclick="ShowHiddenText();">click me to show hidden text</span>
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/JVYq7/).

**Edit**: in case you got more than one element to show, you can use the `rel` attribute:

```
<span rel="HiddenTextContainer2">click me to show second hidden text</span><br />
```

Then with pure JavaScript iterate over all elements with that attribute and assign their `onclick` programmatically:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var id = element.getAttribute("rel") || "";
        if (id.length > 0) {
            element.onclick = function() {
                var oToShow = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("rel"));
                if (oToShow)
                    oToShow.style.display = "block";
            };
        }
    }
};
```

When clicked, element with ID the same as the `rel` value will be displayed.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVYq7/1/).

**Edit**: to show it in one single container, first have such container:

```
<div id="HiddenTextContainer"></div>
```

No need to have it hidden since it's initially empty, then change the code to:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var id = element.getAttribute("rel") || "";
        if (id.length > 0) {
            element.onclick = function() {
                var oToShow = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("rel"));
                if (oToShow)
                    document.getElementById("HiddenTextContainer").innerHTML = oToShow.innerHTML;
            };
        }
    }
};
```

Instead of showing the related container, you copy its contents to the "main" container.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVYq7/2/).

Comment: Don't have Safari but hard to believe such basic code won't work. Do you get JS error? Can you test with other browser?

Comment: it was multiple variations aswell, would be easy to have alternating revealing texts in the same position? thanks for your help

Comment: You mean you have more than one hidden text?

Comment: two seperate bodys of text, one more for the info and contact information. maybe more complicated than i thought

Comment: it was more for an alternating text. so when one is viewed, the other is hidden, and they're both revealed in the same place. is that possible? i think it might require a look into jquery, ill look into some tutorials and come back with a more directed question. thanks again for your help though, really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices for this. The first is to preload everything on the page and then only set the visible property when you click the link. The second is to load it in using something like AJAX and then show it the same way as above.

To show these things look into JQuery: http://jquery.com/

A good tutorial for the second method is here: http://yensdesign.com/2008/12/how-to-load-content-via-ajax-in-jquery/

Comment: got literally within a few tutorials. jquery is amazing. cheers!